# How to save html2canvas as a pdf file

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, html2canvas

I have used the below html2canvas code to append the canvas below the body of the document, but I want to target a specific div and save it as a pdf?

```
    function getscreenshot() {
        html2canvas(document.body, {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, make sure to pass div id you want to export into pdf and name (in case you want to export multiple pdf on the same page. You can take off the name part away if you feel, just make sure to remove it from the pdfmake line as well) as parameter to that function

```
function getscreenshot(div, name) {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById(div), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    width: 500,
                }]
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download( name + ".pdf");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Manuel Vidal, is this how I would call the function from the button in the C# script? 'main' is the name of the div, and 'mcn' the name of the file I want to save it as:                                                                                   protected void Print_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "mykey", "getscreenshot(main,mcn);", true);
    }

Comment: To be honest, I can't answer that since I have no knowledge on that matter.

Comment: Thank you @Manuel Vidal, works great for the document,body, but struggling to make it work for a single div...will keep trying!